# Javascript test string for lower case in any language

Tags: javascript

Hi I need test javascript string for any lower latters i have build next code:

```
var LOWER = /[a-z]/;
var lower = LOWER.test('mystring');
```

but If string contain any special chars from other languages this code not working.
and is is logical my test is just for English latter.
How to write test for any language ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function isLowerCase(s){
    return s==s.toLowerCase()
}
isLowerCase('mystring');
```

`toLowerCase` respects the unicode standard.

Some examples:

`isLowerCase('ä')==true`

`isLowerCase('Ä')==false`